# Running 'amplify mock' resets the changes to queries, mutations

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

**Scenario:**

1. I created a react project following the steps given on AWS Amplify docs [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/react)
2. I answered ***yes*** to the question `Do you want to generate/update all possible GraphQL operations queries, mutations and subscriptions?`
3. Everything worked as expected locally, I tested using `amplify mock`
4. When the project was getting towards completion, I pushed to the cloud using `amplify push`
5. ***I made changes to*** the default `list`, `get` and `update` functions in the following (auto-generated) files:

- `src/graphql/queries`
- `src/graphql/mutations`

7. the app worked as expected
8. ***the problem came when*** I did 'amplify mock' after I had done `amplify push` earlier already (step 6)
9. all my changes to the `src/graphql/queries` and `src/graphql/mutations` files were overwritten by the system on running `amplify mock`
10. I was able to reproduce this scenario again and again... each time that I ran `amplify mock` it reset the `src/graphql/queries` and `src/graphql/mutations` files.

My **Question**:

- How to avoid this from happening?
- I can create new files instead of changing `src/graphql/queries` and `src/graphql/mutations` files?
- or is there a better solution or a step that I am missing?

relevant dependencies in my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^3.4.1",
    "@aws-amplify/cli": "^4.28.2",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.17",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I have now run into this situation myself and have a solution that's working for me.

The best option I see is to create your own files inside `src/graphql` for custom queries/mutations. For instance, I wanted to create queries that return less data than the auto-generated queries. So, I created `src/graphql/queriesCustom.ts` (I'm using typescript, hence the `.ts`). Inside, I copied the query I wanted, updated the variable name and the operation name. When running `push` or `codegen` it updates the auto-generated files as expected but leaves my custom files alone.

Here's an example.

In `src/graphql/queries.ts` there's a `getUser` query like this:

```
export const getUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      type
      username
      email
      avatar
      name
      bio
      categories
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

I wanted a simpler query for a portion of my app. So, I created `src/graphql/queriesCustom.ts`, copied the query, and updated it appropriately:

```
export const getUserSimple = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUserSimple($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      username
      avatar
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Note, you're only changing the operation name and not the query name. So `query GetUser` changed to `query GetUserSimple`. The actual query name of `getUser` stays the same as this is what maps to the resolver in appsync.

Comment: Schema.graphql includes the model(schema)... I wanted my own mutations/queries (in the `src/graphql`) and wrote them and they worked... the annoyance is having them revert to default on each `amplify mock`

Comment: Have you tried putting them in the schema.graphql file? The mutations/queries files are auto-generated. I think the other option is to create your own file like `customMutations` to store yours in.